# calculate factorial recursive in functional style Java

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

I try to calculate factorial in a functional style.

I did this:

```
 private static Function<BigInteger, BigInteger> factorial = x -> BigInteger.ONE.equals(x)
        ? BigInteger.ONE
        : x.multiply(Main.factorial.apply(x.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
```

And I have got `StackOverflowError` when trying to get **`11111`!**

BUT when I calculate factorial using this method:

```
private static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger request) {
    if (BigInteger.ONE.equals(request)) return BigInteger.ONE;
    else return request.multiply(factorial(request.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
}
```

I can get the result without `StackOverflowError`.

Is functional style less effective? Why?

Comment: I am confused. What does this have to do with "Sum of all elements in array"?

Comment: This has nothing to do with functional style perse (btw: both are equally functional style), the main difference - as a guess - could be that lambda's might incur additional overhead that could increase the stack size per call, so you'll run out of stack space quicker.

Comment: @JörgWMittag sorry for the misunderstanding) I forgot to change the name of the question, at first I wanted to take an example from a book about algorithms, but then replaced it with factorial calculation

Comment: Maybe it creates a new instace of the functional interface any time and it is allocated on the stack for optimization...

Comment: Java has no optimization for tail-recursion, so there is always a limit. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354898/tail-call-optimisation-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are twice as many calls in the functional style as compared to function calls.  see image.

[image: Functional Style - double stacks]

[image: Function invocation - single stacks]

So while the stack size increases to 11,111 calls in latter, it increases by over 22,222 calls in functional style. I believe stack limit in your environment should be between 11111 and 22222 so that explains why it breaks. So in this sense Functional style seems inefficient.

You can increase the stack size using `-Xss` described in the below link.

Or, better to use tail recursion which looks something like this:

```
private static BiFunction<BigInteger, BigInteger, BigInteger> factorialTR = (n, acc) -> BigInteger.ONE.equals(x)
    ? BigInteger.ONE
    : Main.factorialTR.apply(x.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), acc * n));
```

This will still cause `StackoverflowError` in Java as it does not support tail call optimization. But Scala, lisp do, there you wont get one.

Refs

- [Tail-recursive factorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tail-recursion/)
- [Leetcode explanation(requires login)](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/recursion-i/256/complexity-analysis/2374/)
- [max stack depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734108/what-is-the-maximum-depth-of-the-java-call-stack)

Comment: I think the question is asking why the lambda fails while a function does not, not *just* why a StackOverflowError happens.

Comment: @17slim Thanks. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Interestingly, in my tests, both versions failed around 13000-150000, and a different number for every test.

Answer (score 1):

Your terminology is somewhat confusing. *Both* of the examples you showed are written in a functional style: there are no side-effects, no mutable state, no loops. Both examples are referentially transparent.

Also, you seem to be under the impression that only one of those examples will throw a `StackOverflowError`. That is not the case. *Both* of those will eventually blow the stack.

In fact, in my testing, both of those blew the stack pretty much at the same value.

For the lambda version, I ran multiple tests, and the stack overflow happened at slightly different values each time, the smallest and biggest ones were around 11000 and around 15300.

For the method version, the stack overflow happened pretty consistently between 13901 and 13907.

Initially, I thought that the lambda version would consistently overflow earlier than the method version, because it uses much more complex runtime machinery (`LambdaMetaFactory`, method handles, call sites, `invokedynamic`) which increases the stack size. But, it looks like more than increase the stack size, it increases the *variance* due to its bigger reliance on runtime optimizations and heuristics.

By the way, your code (both versions) has the same two bugs (which are actually the same bug): it doesn't handle factorial of zero (which is one) and it runs into an infinite recursion for negative numbers. A more correct version would be something like:

```java
private static Function<BigInteger, BigInteger> factorial = 
    x ->
        x.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0
        ? throw new ArgumentError()
        : BigInteger.ZERO.equals(x)
          ? BigInteger.ONE
          : x.multiply(App.factorial.apply(x.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));

private static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger request) {
    if (request.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) throw new ArgumentError;
    if (BigInteger.ZERO.equals(request)) return BigInteger.ONE;
    else return request.multiply(factorial(request.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
}
```